# Stuck in a constant loop

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception

I have my StoreFront class that calls this method when I select option 3 to return a product. This method is supposed to ask me `"Enter the name of the product you want to return: "` I type in the product put my console just prompts me again saying `"Enter the name of the product you want to return: "`. Unsure where to go from here? Why am I stuck in a constant loop? Here is my method as well

```
    public SalableProduct returnProduct(String name) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the product you want to return: ");
        String returnProd = scnr.nextLine();

        SalableProduct productReturned = returnProduct(returnProd);
        if (productReturned == null) {
            System.out.println("Item not in cart");
        } else {
            removeItem(productReturned);
            addItem(productReturned);
            System.out.println(productReturned.getName() + " successfully returned");
        }scnr.close();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: There's no loop in the code you've shown.

Comment: you are calling this method recursively 
You need to add a break condition for this line
SalableProduct productReturned = returnProduct(returnProd);

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a break condition. I also added a for loop that iterates over the products in the salableProduct list. I will add my refactored code to this.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored my code and added a for loop so it will check over the products in my cart and then will break once it has iterated through.

```
    public void returnProduct(String name) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the product you want to return: ");
        String returnProd = scnr.nextLine();

        SalableProduct productReturned = null;

        for (SalableProduct product : salableProduct) {
            if (product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(returnProd)) {
                productReturned = product;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (productReturned == null) {
            System.out.println("Item not in cart");
        } else {
            removeItem(productReturned);
            InventoryManager inventoryManager = new InventoryManager();
            inventoryManager.addProduct(productReturned);
            System.out.println(productReturned.getName() + " successfully returned");
        }

        scnr.close();
    }
```

Another bug came up where the program would exit because scnr.close() is tied to System.in so I used custom FilterInputStream and wrapped System.in.

UPDATED CODE:

```
    public void returnProduct(String name) {
        FilterInputStream filterInputStream = new FilterInputStream(System.in) {
            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
            }
        };
        // FilterInputStream so when scanner is closed it does not quit the program and
        // handles errors.
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(filterInputStream);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the product you want to return: ");
        String returnProd = scnr.nextLine();

        SalableProduct productReturned = null;
        for (SalableProduct product : salableProduct) {
            if (product.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(returnProd)) {
                productReturned = product;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (productReturned == null) {
            System.out.println("Item not in cart");
        } else {
            removeItem(productReturned);
            InventoryManager inventoryManager = new InventoryManager();
            inventoryManager.addProduct(productReturned);
            System.out.println(productReturned.getName() + " successfully returned");
        }

        scnr.close();
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't close the Scanner since it is operating on System.in, which you did not open.

Comment: Yes I actually just noticed that after I got my loop issue fixed. But I just got done adding FilterInputStream and wrapping System.in so that it overrides to prevent System.in being closed when scnr is closed. I will add the code for reference.